# Adding Google-managed, auto-renewing SSL custom domain with cloudflare DNS

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

Trying to enable auto renewing SSL on google app engine but google says DNS records can not be found.

[image]

I have added them for subdomain, tried doing all A and AAAA records or just CNAME record (as cloudflare doesn't allow CNAME and A,AAAA on same subdomain), but no luck with google finding DNS records (even after waiting 24 hours).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever DNS records are needed by google to verify ownership of the domain should not be orange clouded/Proxied, they should be grey clouded/DNS only. Proxying will actually cause cloudflare to serve an A / AAAA record for their own servers/ips and on the requests to your origin server, they will use these entries. Google would not see the actual DNS entries to do the verification.

That being said, the A / AAAA records in your picture don't look like the verification records.  I don't know anything about GCP/GAE, but generally the domain control verification records are TXT records or CNAME records. Regardless of this, the above applies. You need the DNS only mode to modify the actual DNS entries that everyone sees.

Comment: Ahh right didn't know that I could change to be not proxied by clicking it. Disabling proxy on cloudflare and using DNS only solved issue

Comment: hi drussey, thank you for the answer. GCP is asking to add A and CNAME records that have the same name, but that's not possible. For example I cannot add subdomain.domain.com as the name for both CNAME and A record at the same time. What should be done in this case?

Comment: @robert-sinclair yes, DNS just won't allow CNAME to co-exist with A. Perhaps GCP means something like subdomain.domain.com CNAME subdomain2.domain.com, subdomain2.domain.com A 123.123.123.123. Sorry I can't help more.