Unable to add custom domain for my web app using GCP App Engine
I have a domain, let say mysideproject.com. I bought the domain from GoDaddy but eventually started managing it on Cloudflare. Used Github to deploy the static frontend landing page by adding the A and AAAA records in Cloudfare DNS entry.
Now, I developed another full stack app and deployed it using GCP App Engine. The app is up and running at app.appspot.com, I want to add a subdomain like app.mysideproject.com that should point to my newly deployed app.
Steps that I did:

On App Engine, verified the ownership of mysideproject.com

Added a subdomain app.mysideproject.com . This gave a bunch of A, AAAA and CNAME records again.

Added the A and AAAA records but CANNOT add the CNAME to Cloudflare as it throws this error:


An A, AAAA, or CNAME record with that host already exists. For more details, refer to <https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/troubleshooting/records-with-same-name/>. (Code: 81053)

So what I have in my DNS is:

A and AAAA records given by Github for mysideproject.com

A and AAAA record given by App Engine for app.mysideproject.com


Also, Google managed SSL certs are stuck and they are never renewed. It throws this error:
DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically.

My redirection to app.mysideproject.com fails because of "SSL handshake failed". Any idea what is going wrong? Any help here will be super appreciated.

Please update your question with your current set of DNS records for this mysideproject.com domain and include the set of records that App Engine requested.

Thank you @DazWilkin for taking a look! However I was able to make it work using the the below answer.

This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62918313/26631844
Basically, the DNS needed by Google to verify the ownership were proxied by Cloudflare. Changing the entries to DNS only worked for me.
